# Ubuntu book/pdf that could help learn the terminal

Tags: command-line

SO guys I’m new in Ubuntu world,right now I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm actually enjoying it, I'm coming from windows, so i want to ask u guys if there's any Ubuntu Book/pd f that could help me learn the Ubuntu terminal and their commands! Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal

Comment: Tons of options see also http://linuxcommand.org/

Comment: Try `man man`. If you want a book, try one on [bash](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/Bash-Beginners-Guide.pdf).

Comment: **[Ubuntu Book](https://github.com/jrgifford/Ubuntu-Book)**

Comment: This is not opinion-based, it is asking for where one can find infromation. I am voting to reopen.

Comment: @don.joey You're right, this isn't so opinion based. But it is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a book for you that I'm surprised no-one has mentioned so far: [The Linux Command Line, A complete Introduction by William E. Shotts, JR.](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php)

It has only been recently published (a year or so ago) and it is wonderful for a newbie, as well as being inexpensive.

Look for online reviews. I think that you will progress faster with this book than mostly any other way.

Buy it, borrow it, or order it from your local/state/educational library.
It is so clearly written it wouldn't overload anyone's brain with an IQ over 85.
I keep mine with me in my shoulderbag and dive in whenever I feel like it.

I would also suggest sticking with 14.04 LTS and don't jump around all the other GNU/Linux distros till you learn it. That will save you loads of time and sensory overload till you're adept.  14.04 is probably close to being one of the best for the majority of people anyway. Hey, the command-line is such a wonderful thing. Stick to it and the love will come.
 This is my beginner's advice as I'm on the path towards the light as well (a sophomore at best but enjoying the journey).

Comment: That was a quite inspirations, I'm gonna stick with it, I will check the book! Looking forward for Linux world, till the experience has been nice! And with the forum askubuntu it's making learn Ubuntu a great and easy way!

Answer (score 4):

I'll go out on a limb, and suggest the [Ubuntu manual.](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/index.html)  I am assuming that you are running the stock distribution, and not a variant such as kubuntu, or xubuntu.

I did actually find a little annoying to find, having to navigate

- --> Ubuntu.com
- --> community
- --> help and information
- --> official documentation
- --> 14.04 LTS
- --> Desktop Guide

But also, the community wiki should be useful as well:

- [Commandline Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommandlineHowto)
- [Commandline resources](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommandLineResources)
- [Using the Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal)

Links from the [most popular pages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PopularPages) page.

Comment: thanks Dude i did check the https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/index.html right before i installed ubuntu 14.04, i will read those links that u post. thanks for the tips <3

Comment: @user272114: If someone's answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.lybrary.com/linux-pocket-guide-p-230616.html?gclid=CKW1_5an8r0CFbFFMgodBE0AYQ

This is a pretty good primer for lots of things. I actually used it once to burn an .ISO image from the terminal. It helped me learn a pretty good deal of info.

It says it is for Red Hat, but for someone who has no terminal experience it works since they talk about some of the basics that apply to ALL distros.

Comment: thanks Dude i was checking the preview!!! thanks for the tip

Comment: I had the print version of this book, which was nice when my system needed some maintenance and I didn't have the internet available to me. Good luck, and welcome to Linux!

Comment: yeah I'm reading it online, then i will print, in fact i don't have a nice internet connection, thanks again it's been couple of days without using windows,for me it's a great deal, looking forward for learning it.

Answer (score 1):

### Don't forget the books!

Though books are generally neglected in the present online world of linux learners, there are several excellent chapters on the command line in linux and Ubuntu:

- Chapter five of "Ubuntu Pocket Guide and Reference: A Concise Companion for Day-To-Day Ubuntu Use" by Keir Thomas
- Chapter nineteen of "Ubuntu Linux Secrets" by Richard Blum
- Chapter fourteen of "Ubuntu 8.10 Linux" by William Von Hagen (an older, but valuable reference)

There is also the more advanced book:

- "Mastering Unix Shell Scripting" by Randall Michael.

Feel free to suggest other books in the comments (or edit them in).

### In the meanwhile

... you can read:

- The [community wiki on the CL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal) (command line)
- [The most frequently used unix commands explained](http://www.computerhope.com/unixtop1.htm)
- [An online book](http://www.linuxcommand.org/learning_the_shell.php) on learning the shell
- [Some very practical tips](http://www.math.utah.edu/lab/unix/unix-commands.html)
- [A database](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/browse) with nice (but probably more complicated) uses of the CL
- [A blog post](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/15-practical-unix-linux-top-command-examples/) with tricks for the commonly used `top` command

...

Comment: Awesome Man! That was a great tip