# looking for a Book on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: command-line

Remember "The Waite Group's M-S DOS Bible"??
I am looking for something with that kind of approachability for Linux Ubuntu.
Do you know of one such?
Thx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu book/pdf that could help learn the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452351/ubuntu-book-pdf-that-could-help-learn-the-terminal)

Answer (score 1):

Try the "Ubuntu Linux Bible" - but there are many more good books about Ubuntu or Linux in general.

If you want to check the insides of linux, check out the pages at [Linux from Scratch](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/).

In addition this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4WyNjt_hbQ) (skip the sponsor's intro to: 3:30 ) takes you from windows to Linux

Comment: thx I just ordered  ‘The Linux Command Line’ by William Shotts

Answer (score 0):

"MS-DOS" is cmd.com in my eyes...

The evolved version of the command line is e.g. Bash and the other "Shell"s.

To get to know Bash you may go to [www.tldp.org](http://www.tldp.org) and get the Bash guides there. They will tell you a lot, with many examples.

That is just one part of Linux, a very useful part though...

Comment: Thx I was unaware of the tldp.

Comment: Now, tldp documents are old, but they still provide information that get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this’ll get closed as it’s seeking opinions (though a good question in my view!).

For general Ubuntu / Linux - your best option is to install it and use it - you’ll get to know it much better than you would by reading a book. And you can ask on this site if you get stuck.

The Ubuntu official documentation (https://help.ubuntu.com/) has lots of useful information.

For the command line (Bash / terminal) - yes, lots of possibilities for reading. I found ‘The Linux Command Line’ by William Shotts to be excellent, taking the absolute beginner up to a reasonable level and it’s really readable. It’s free to download.